# log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties does not work correctly with OwinMiddleware

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I am trying to use log4net.LogicalThreadContext to store some data in the OwinMiddleware, so i can log it later in the ApiController, but it doesn't seem to work. The data stored in log4net.LogicalThreadContext doesn't seems to make it available in the ApiController. Here is my code snippet:

Created the ApiMiddleWare in order to inject some log data to LogicalThreadContext.Properties["logdata"]:

```
public class ApiMiddleWare : OwinMiddleware
{
    public ApiMiddleWare(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {

        var loggers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
        if (!loggers.ContainsKey("CorellationId"))
        {
            var correlationId = new[] {Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "")};
            loggers.TryAdd("CorellationId", correlationId[0]);
        }
        if (context.Request.Path.HasValue)
        {
            loggers.TryAdd("Route", context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        LogicalThreadContext.Properties["logdata"] = loggers;

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Then ApiMiddleWare will be used in Startup.cs in ServiceHost as below:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<ApiMiddleWare>();
        Log.Configure();
    }

}
```

I created a custom RollingFileAppeanderEx to capture log data that was assigned in the middleware and log it:

```
public class RollingFileAppenderEx: RollingFileAppender
{
    protected static readonly JsonSerializerSettings JsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
    };
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (FilterEvent(loggingEvent))
        {
            var logdata = loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData();
            logdata.Message = GetLogData(loggingEvent);
            loggingEvent = new LoggingEvent(loggingEvent.GetType(), loggingEvent.Repository, logdata, loggingEvent.Fix);
            base.Append(loggingEvent);
        }

    }

    protected string GetLogData(LoggingEvent logEvent)
    {

        IDictionary<string, object> logData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var logD = logEvent.Properties["logdata"] as ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>;
        if logD != null)
        {
            foreach (var log in logD)
            {
                logData.Add(log.Key, log.Value);
            }
        }
        logData.Add("Message", logObject.Message);

        var logString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logData, JsonSettings);
        return logString;
    }

}
```

From The ApiController, call Info function to log:

```
public class TestsController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly ILogger Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);  
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        Log.Info("Something");
        return id;
    }
}
```

Here is my problem: Only "Something" was written to the log. However, CorellationId and  Route were not. Debugging through the code, I found that "logEvent.Properties["logdata"] as ConcurrentDictionary" returned nullable value in the RollingFileAppenderEx. So i have a theory: it seems that TestsController class is not in the same thread or not a child thread  from ApiMiddleWare. Therefore, data stored in LogicalThreadContext does not propagate all the way.

If anyone can help to see if there is a way to do this, or maybe there is a bug in my code. I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Last time I checked the source, log4net's logical data implementation was incomplete. Have you tried using `AsyncLocal<T>`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried AsyncLocal<T>, it doesn't world either. I actually used AsyncLocal<T> to be sure that the issue isn't happening only in LogicalThreadContext.Properties.

Comment: You are running on 4.5 or higher, right?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of log4net? There were issues with LogicalThreadContext in previous versions.

Comment: yes, I got the latest log4net. I ended up using config.MessageHandlers.Add() in WebApiConfig.cs instead of Owin and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to call `loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData()`?

I had:

```
public abstract class AwsVerboseLogsAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    // ...
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

// ...

var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "log4net.config");
var fileinfo = new FileInfo(path);
XmlConfigurator.Configure(fileinfo);
var log = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());

LogicalThreadContext.Properties["Test"] = "MyValue";

log.Debug("test");
```

And `loggingEvent.Properties` was empty inside `Append`.

However if I called `loggingEvent.GetLoggingEventData()`, then `"Test"` and `MyValue` showed up inside `loggingEvent.Properties`.  So maybe you have to call that method.